# Making Bash modular

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bunch of Bash scripts and they each make use of the following:

```
BIN_CHATTR="/usr/bin/chattr"
BIN_CHKCONFIG="/sbin/chkconfig";
BIN_WGET="/usr/bin/wget";
BIN_TOUCH="/bin/touch";
BIN_TAR="/bin/tar";
BIN_CHMOD="/bin/chmod";
BIN_CHOWN="/bin/chown";
BIN_ECHO="/bin/echo";
BIN_GUNZIP="/usr/bin/gunzip";
BIN_PATCH="/usr/bin/patch";
BIN_FIND="/usr/bin/find";
BIN_RM="/bin/rm";
BIN_USERDEL="/usr/sbin/userdel";
BIN_GROUPDEL="/usr/sbin/groupdel";
BIN_MOUNT="/bin/mount";
```

Is there a way I could just wget a Bash script with global settings like that and then include them in the script I want to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Just add your variables and functions to a file, make it executable and "execute" it at the top of any script that needs to access them. Here's an example:

```
$ pwd
/Users/joe/shell

$ cat lib.sh 
#!/bin/bash
BIN_WGET="/usr/bin/wget"
BIN_MOUNT="/bin/mount"

function test() {
    echo "This is a test"
}

$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

. /Users/joe/shell/lib.sh

echo "wget=$BIN_WGET"

test


$ ./script.sh 
wget=/usr/bin/wget
This is a test
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can put all those variables in a file like "settings.sh" and then do this in your scripts:

```
source settings.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

You can keep your variables in a shell script and then source that file:

```
source /path/to/variables.sh
```

You should actually use `.` which in bash is the same thing as source but will offer better portability:

```
. /path/to/variables.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for the source command?

mylib.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
JAIL_ROOT=/www/httpd
is_root(){
   [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ] && return $TRUE || return $FALSE
}
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Load the  mylib.sh using source comamnd
source mylib.sh

echo "JAIL_ROOT is set to $JAIL_ROOT"

# Invoke the is_root() and show message to user
is_root && echo "You are logged in as root." || echo "You are not logged in as root."
```

btw - use rsync -a to mirror scripts with +x flag.